# React Native: Get Lifecycle or LifecycleOwner in native module

Tags: android, kotlin, react-native, androidx

I'm developing a native module for React Native which wraps the CameraX API. The CameraX API is a lifecycle-aware API, so it requires me to pass an androidx [`Lifecycle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Lifecycle) (or androidx [`LifecycleOwner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LifecycleOwner)) into it's constructor.

Since those are androidx classes, there's no way to obtain a `Lifecycle` (or `LifecycleOwner`) from the React Native context.

There is however [`ReactContext::addLifecycleEventListener`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/edbe154a3043d6116b04af9016711f31311b409e/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/bridge/ReactContext.java#L184-L211), which is a custom lifecycle event listener implementation by React Native ([`LifecycleEventListener`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/6e6443afd04a847ef23fb6254a84e48c70b45896/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/bridge/LifecycleEventListener.java)), which I am now trying to "convert"/map to an androidx `Lifecycle` (or `LifecycleOwner`), but I can't figure out how.

```kotlin
val lifecycle: Lifecycle = ???

reactContext.addLifecycleEventListener(object : LifecycleEventListener {
    override fun onHostResume() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onHostPause() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onHostDestroy() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
})

cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycle, cameraSelector, preview)
```

My question is now: How do I "create" a `Lifecycle` (or `LifecycleOwner`) instance from my React  lifecycle?

I'd appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to cast the current activity from the react context:

```kotlin
private val lifecycle: Lifecycle by lazy {
    ((context as ReactContext).currentActivity as AppCompatActivity).lifecycle
}
```